# redux: IDs vs objects

Tags: javascript, redux

[Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) gives an example of storage that keeps posts and comments. To reduce complicity of nested objects it suggests to keep comments as array of IDs.

So the code of posts reducer will look like this:

```
function postsById(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_COMMENT':
      var { commentId, postId, commentText } = action.payload;
      var post = state[postId];
      return {
        ...state,
        [postId]: {
          ...post,
          comments: post.comments.concat(commentId)
        }
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

**But why not keep the whole objects there:**

```
...
return {
  ...state,
  [postId]: {
    ...post,
    comments: post.comments.concat(
      {commentId, commentText}  // <=
    )
  }
}
...
```

If we do so we don't need to use complex selectors and computations to get required data:

```
// keeping IDs
function getPostComments(state, postId) {
  return state.postsById[postId].comments.map(
    commentId => state.commentsById[commentId]
  )
}

// keeping objects
function getPostComments(state, postId) {
  return state.postsById[postId].comments
}
```

Though this example is very simple, in other cases keeping the whole objects will make complex selectors much easier.

Comment: The idea is to keep the complete objects in exactly one container object (keyed by id). Then you may keep several arrays of ids. This reduces the amount of memory the browser will need to use and also frees you from having to make sure multiple copies of the objects are kept up-to-date. If you will never need to access the comments except as children of the posts, you can keep them in their respective posts.

Comment: @Tex. **1)** To reduce amount of memory I can point the same object everywhere (`action.payload` for example). **2)** I can keep objects up-to-date the same way i keep  IDs up-to-date. **3)** Keeping comment objects in array doesn't stop me from keeping them keyed by ids too.

Comment: I think the likely outcome would be a transfer of complexity from the selectors to the reducers rather than a reduction in the overall complexity of the system.